# Logical indexing creates row instead of column

Tags: matlab, indexing

I am failing to understand the behaviour of Matlab I've just discovered. Here is the code:

```
ix = logical([1; 0; 1]);
value = [2; 2; 2];
newValue(ix) = value(ix)
```

It outputs

```
2 0 2
```

while I expect

```
2
0
2
```

I can “correct” it by adding `newValue = nan(size(value))` before my code. But I would like to understand *why* Matlab creates a row from column vectors.

Comment: I don't know WHY either, but you can get your expected result with `newValue(ix,:) = value(ix)` (if `newValue` dos not exist, otherwise you should initialise it as you did).

Comment: @Zep, the trouble is that I would like the output of my function to have the same dimension as the input (as is the case e.g. with the built-in `sin`). However without preallocation it doesn't work, as described. And the fact that it doesn't work indicates I am missing something fundamental about dimensions in Matlab. So it puzzles me, from the first principles :)

Comment: I think @Théo P. answered you: Matlab creates rows by default. If you want a column, either preallocate or specify it in the indexing (`newValue(ix,:)`).

Answer (score 4):

It does this behavior because when you create an array using indexing: `a(1) = 2; a(2) = 3;`, Matlab (and Octave) create a row (`a=[2, 3]`). And when you use logical indexing it use this method. In your case Matlab executes

```
newValue(1) = value(1); 
newValue(3) = value(3);
```

But as @Irreducible says, you can avoid this by pre-allocating newValue

And you can obtain the same results without using logical indexing with:

```
ix = [1; 0; 1];
value = [2; 2; 2];
newValue = value.*ix;
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that it has anything to do with logical indexing. You can reproduce the same behavior with

```
ix=[1;2;3]
value = [2; 2; 2];
newValue(ix)=value(ix)

newValue =

 2     2     2
```

I assume that the default format (newValue) is a row and that is why you get this result (as you can see if you create x=1:3).

```
x=1:3;
x =

 1     2     3
```

By pre-allocating newValue you can overcome this.

```
newValue=zeros(size(value));
```

or by post processing it

```
newValue=newValue(:);
```